# On one click open 2 pages but not simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css

ok I want a help with a code, when user click the "download", it should go to the first link but if link 1 is down,  it should go to 2nd link ........link 1 should be a default, it should only send the visitor to 2nd link if 1st link dead or down

please tell me if this kind of thing is possible, or just my imagination

and it will be great if the 2nd link is hidden which can't found out by simple inspect tool,if not possible just forget the last line

Comment: Post code with your questions. Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: ^ Welcome to SO. You would probably end up doing a simple AJAX network request, although a preferred method would be to do this server side. Yes, it's possible, but we can't help you without you showing your work first.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a call and check the return status with AJAX. Then based on the status code such as 200,404, you can decide what you want to do. This can be done easier with jQuery.ajax() method if you use jQuery.

One of the approach would be to check the URL and recieve the status with AJAX. Based on the returned status code (example 404), you decide what to do next:

**with jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://yoursite.com/pagename.php',
    success: function() {
        // NO 404 ERROR
    },
    error: function() {
        // error in HEAD (404)
    }
});
```

**with Pure Javascript:**

```
function checkUrl(url) {
    var request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }

    if (request) {
            request.open("GET", url);
            if (request.status == 200) { return true; }
    }

    return false;
```